# OAuth tokens for Wordpress Mobile

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, wordpress

I am trying to test locally the WP iOS app and I have a problem with login in.
I have a created an app at developer.wordpress.com and I have authorized it for my account via the web.

In `WordPressComApi.m` I have copied the app_id and secret_key that I found at developer.wordpress.com

When I build the app and try to login I get the following response:

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Client cannot use \"password\" grant_type"}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a hosting site with wordpress to test it out. check [wordpress.org](http://make.wordpress.org/mobile/handbook/general-guides/connecting-to-wordpress-com/) out